# Sending Output of Terminal Command via curl using a Slack Webhook

Tags: arrays, bash, curl, slack-api

For the sake of context, I am developing a system which would allow "remote" access to an NVidia Xavier. Unfortunately in its current housing, the display port is entirely blocked unless the entire unit is taken apart. A USB port is available, which is being used to connect to a wireless keyboard & mouse. I have already written a Gstreamer pipeline that I can execute via SSH which will capture the display and stream it to another local machine.

The problem I am running in to is, as the unit is portable, the network it is connected to and subsequent IP will be constantly changing, but I need to know it to be able to SSH into the unit.

I am trying to write a (what I thought to be simple) bash script that will send a timestamp and the IP of the unit to a Slack channel on boot via a webhook that is effectively the following command (IP and slack URL generalized):

`curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"Tue Jul 14 15:26:50 EDT 2020 IP: XX.X.X.XX"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/T00000000/B00000000/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

The JSON payload will be changing each time the script is run, dependent on the results of `hostname -I` and `date`.

I have tried creating an array with the desired data in it using:

`command=( -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data \'{\"text\":\")`

`command+=("$(date)")`

`command+=("$(hostname -I)")`

`command+=(\"}\' https://hooks.slack.com/services/T00000000/B00000000/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)`

`curl command`

but receive an error `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: command`.

I have very little experience writing bash scripts and am likely missing something incredibly obvious to everyone else. However, using `echo "${command[*]}"` does show an output that matches the working command. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common error when using variables in bash - when you set them, you don't prefix them with a `$`, but when you reference them, they must be prefixed with a `$` in order to be expanded. So in your case, you likely want to use: `curl $command` instead of `curl command`